# Refactoring a nested if statement: first check if block exists, then apply another if statement on block.call

Tags: ruby, if-statement, refactoring, nested

I have the following method that accepts an optional block and I've written it the following way:

```
def top_method(&block)
  if block
    if block.call == 1
      another_method_1
      another_method_2
    end
  else
    another_method_3
  end
end
```

At first I thought it's possible to refactor as follows:

```
if block.call == 1
  another_method_1
  another_method_2
else
  another_method_3
end
```

But I'm getting the error on `block.call` (where `call` is called on `nil`) if no block was passed to `top_method`. Is there a way to rewrite the method above with just one condition in the first `if` statement (like skipping it when it gets an error)?

Also, I would like to know if I can refactor the inner `if` statement into one line. Is there a way to do this? What I mean is as follows:

```
if block
  (run another_method_1 and another_method_2) if block.call == 1
end
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your first snippet and your second have a fundamental difference beyond the error you're getting: The top snippet, if the block is present but returns other than 1, _does nothing_.  The second snippet, if the block is present and returns other than 1, calls `another_method_3`.  Which of the two is your intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can offer tricks, but what I think this code really needs is some object oriented programming.  However, without knowing the semantics of what you're doing it's difficult to come up with an improved design.  So, a trick instead.

You might consider giving the block a default value.  As noted in comments, there's currently some ambiguity in what you want to do.  Here I assume the semantics of your second snippet:

```
def top_method(&block)
  block ||= lambda {}
  if block.call == 1
    another_method_1
    another_method_2
  else
    another_method_3
  end
end
```

If no block is passed in, then block is set to `lambda {}`.  Lambda behaves, in this case, just like a block: it responds to *call*, and has a return value.  In this case, having an empty body, it returns *nil*.  Since *nil* is not equal to 1, the *else* part of the *if* will be executed.

Comment: you don't need the `0` in the lambda. You can just say `&block = lambda {}`, or in 1.9+ `&block = ->{}`

Comment: @WayneConrad, thanks for the trick. I tried to run this but now I get a syntax error:

    `SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
    def top_method(&block = lambda {})
                           ^
    (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end`

Comment: @adler, Shame on me.  I've fixed the syntax error, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the 2 inner conditions into 1 statement.

```
def top_method(&block)
  if block && block.call
    another_method1
    another_method2
  else
    another_method3
  end
end
```

Comment: The call to block will error as well if it doesn't exist.  You want to use `block_given?` to check.

Comment: @vgoff, the "if block" does the same thing, in this case, as checking `block_given?`: since block is being made an explicit parameter, it gets assigned _nil_ if the block is not present.

Comment: The condition block.call is not very useful--and certainly doesn't do what the op asked.

Comment: you probably mean `if block && block.call == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def top_method(&block)
  if block_given? && block.call == 1
    1
    2
  else
    3
  end
end

puts top_method
puts top_method {1}
```

Comment: ++ for using block_given?, but -- for not doing what the op wants, i.e. checking the return value of the block to determine the next course of action.  yield is of no help.

Comment: You are so right.  Going to use a logic operator there.  Which means I can't use a yield.  I was concentrating on the fact that yield returns from the method.  Thanks.

Comment: I prefer Wayne's answer better though, as it provides for a Proc (as a lambda) by default.

Comment: I would think that checking the contents of a variable is more efficient than calling a do nothing method--and imo the default is ugly clutter.

Comment: Agree about performance, but if the performance hit needs to happen anyway, delay it until the method is called?  And why a default proc is needed if asking if the block is given, I agree with.  The benefit though is his code just doesn't ask, it tells.

Comment: `but if the performance hit needs to happen anyway`  It doesn't obviously--otherwise there would be no need for an if statement.  `The benefit though is his code just doesn't ask, it tells.`  Ridiculous clap-trap.  But if the artistry of the code speaks to you in some way, so be it.

Comment: Perhaps, but I was commenting to get an answer, as I am unsure.  I did miss a question mark in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
def top_method(&block)
  if block and block.call == 1
    method1
    method2
  else
    method3
  end
end
```

..

> Also, I would like to know if I can refactor the inner if statement
>   into one line. Is there a way to do this? What I mean is as follows:
>
> ```
>     if block
>       (run another_method_1 and another_method_2) if block.call == 1
>     end
>
> Thanks in advance! :)
> ```

Sure--if you want to join the hoard of people who write poor ruby.  And then you would still have to write an if statement to handle your else clause.  One liners should never be your goal.  Code clarity is much more important.

```
lambda {meth1;meth2}.call if block and block.call == 1
```